# Passing variables in and out of functions

Tags: python, function, global-variables, local-variables

I've written a small program to do the following:

- inspect an image
- pick a row at random from the image
- plot the pixel values along that row
- make a `list` of the local minima in that row

and I'm trying to make it into a function, so that I do the same thing to, say 10 rows, so that I can plot the pixel values of all of those rows without haveing to run the program 10 times.
The code looks like this:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

hdulist = fits.open('xbulge-w1.fits')   #   Open FITS file as image
w1data = hdulist[0].data

height = w1data.shape[0]    #   Inspect height of image
width = w1data.shape[1]

def plot_envelope(image, image_height):
    index = np.random.randint(0, height/2)  #   Select random number in upper half
    row = w1data[index]   #   Look at row number

    local_minima = []

    #   Find local minimum, and add to list of minimum-valued pixels
    for i in range(1, width-1):
        if w1data[index][i-1] > w1data[index][i]:
            if w1data[index][i+1] > w1data[index][i]:
                local_minima.append(w1data[index][i])
        else:
            continue
    return (local_minima, row, index)

plot_envelope(w1data, height)

x1 = range(width)
plt.plot(x1, row, color = 'r', linewidth = 0.5)
plt.title('Local envelope for row ' + str(index))
plt.xlabel('Position')
plt.ylabel('Pixel value')
plt.show()
```

It works fine if I don't use a function definition (i.e. if the declarations of `index`, `row`, and `local_minima` and the nested `for` loops are in the `main` part of the program). With the function definition as shown, it returns a `NameError: name 'local_minima' is not defined` error.
Since I'm passing those variables out of the function, shouldn't I be able to use them in the rest of the program?
Am I missing something about local and global variables?

Comment: Where do you get the `NameError`? I don't see how the code posted would return a `NameError` for `local_minima` unless it is in some other part of the code that you haven't shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `plot_envelope(w1data, height)` you are telling the function to assign w1data and height to image and image_heigth respectivelly. Inside the function you should manipulate the `w1data` with the `image` dummy variable (change w1data for image inside the function) , which scope is only inside the function. Next thing is that you should get the result of the function (return) in a variable:  `envelope = plot_envelope(w1data, height)` Then `local_minima = envelope[0], row = envelope[1], index = envelope[2]`.

Comment: An alternative call would be `local_minima, row, index = plot_envelope(w1data, height)`.